# Did the unsolved XOR problem in "Perceptrons: An Introduction to Computational Geometry" 1969 book really cause the winter of the AI in 1974?

Tags: reference-request, history, perceptron, xor-problem, ai-winter

Winter of AI definition:

> periods of reduced funding and interest in artificial intelligence research, due to unmet expectations after a period of hype. There have been at least two major AI winters in 1974-1980 and 1987-1993.

I read this question: [Did Minsky and Papert know that multi-layer perceptrons could solve XOR?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1288/2444)

> Minsky and Papert show that a perceptron can't solve the XOR problem. **This contributed to the first AI winter**, **resulting in funding cuts for neural networks.** However, now we know that a multilayer perceptron can solve the XOR problem easily.

Does someone have evidence to support that the "unsolved XOR problem" in Minsky and Papert's book caused the first winter of the AI? Or was it a succession of unsolved problems for neural networks and loss of interest that caused the cuts on funding?

Comment: Notice that the excerpt you quote uses the term "contributed", *not* "caused".